# RichFaces r:tabPanel

Tags: ajax, jsf, tabs, richfaces, tabpanel

I got a `TabPanel` with 3 `r:tabs` nested in a `collapsiblePanel`

The `r:tabPanel` and `r:collapsiblePanel` are both `switchType="ajax"`

> **ajax**
>
> AJAX form submission is performed around the tabPanel, content of the
>   called tabPanel is uploaded on Ajax request. Only one at a time
>   tabPanel is uploaded on the client.

Each panel has some criteria the client can enter,

let's have the fictive scenario:

```
Tab 1:
Date = 01.01.2000

Tab 2:
Size >= 200MB

Tab 3: 
Archived Yes/No (Checkbox)
```

when I am on Tab 1, and submit the form, everything works fine, and I get the proper search results.

However if I try to submit(`searchButton`) while Tab 2 is active, nothing happens.

Is there any documentation, where this may bug?

Code Snippet:

```
<h:panelGrid>
                <!--  search panel -->
                <r:collapsiblePanel id="searchPanel" header="Suche"
                    toggleListener="#{meldungListBacking.toggleSearchPanel}"
                    switchType="ajax" immediate="true"
                    expanded="#{meldungListBacking.searchPanelOpened}">
                    <r:tabPanel selectedTab="criteria" switchType="ajax">
                        <r:tab id="criteria"
                            header="#{res.meldungList_search_tab_criteria_label}"
                            styleClass="textlenght">...
                        </r:tab>
                        <r:tab id="othercriteria"
                            header="#{res.meldungList_search_tab_criteria_label}"
                            styleClass="textlenght">...
                        </r:tab>
                        <r:tab id="evenothercriteria"
                            header="#{res.meldungList_search_tab_criteria_label}"
                            styleClass="textlenght">...
                        </r:tab>
                    </r:tabPanel>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:commandButton id="searchButton" value="Suchen"
                            action="#{uebergreifendeLeistungswertListController.search}">

                        </h:commandButton>
                        <h:commandButton id="resetButton"
                            value="#{res.global_button_Ruecksetzen}"
                            action="#{uebergreifendeLeistungswertListController.reset}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Ajax 'queueing' ?

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't use any JS code here or what do you mean?

Comment: Have you tried placing the searchButton outside the collapsiblePanel? Maybe chaning the tab changes the collapsiblePanel so it is not able to submit. Is the Button working again if you switch from tab 2 back to tab 1?

Comment: Where did I mention JS? I mentioned ajax as used in your tags and quote about what ajax is...

Comment: http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=queue&skin=blueSky and http://jsfcentral.com/articles/richfaces_queue.html